# Vue-Material not loading fonts

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I've imported vue-material to my nuxt.js project from the plugins folder:

> **~/plugins/VueMaterial.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import 'vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css'
import 'vue-material/dist/theme/default.css'

Vue.use(VueMaterial)
```

then, on my nuxt.config.js:

> **~/nuxt.config.js**

```js
plugins: ['~/plugins/VueMaterial.js']
...
build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    },
    transpile: ['vue-material']
  }
```

And added to my template:

> **~/layouts/default.vu**

```html
<template>
  <div class="pt-10">
    <nuxt />
    <div class="phone-viewport">
      <md-bottom-bar md-type="shift">
        <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-home" md-label="Home" md-icon="home"></md-bottom-bar-item>
        <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-pages" md-label="Pages" md-icon="pages"></md-bottom-bar-item>
        <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-posts" md-label="Posts" md-icon="Home"></md-bottom-bar-item>
        <md-bottom-bar-item id="bottom-bar-item-favorites" md-label="Favorites" md-icon="favorite"></md-bottom-bar-item>
      </md-bottom-bar>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

But the styles are not loaded properly
[image: Bottom bar Vue-Material]

Comment: removed the  md-type="" from md-bottom-bar and the items get the full width of the page.

Comment: <md-bottom-bar md-type="fixed"  every time i add a md-type it shows the same issue on the image